# Many Internal Server Errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, npm, webpack

Due to some package incompatibilities I have updated my package.json to the latest version for most of the entries, however now when I start the application it displays this long list of errors in the browser:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>   AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Dll Reference Plugin Invalid Options
>
> options.manifest.content['./node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
>
> options.manifest.content['./node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
>
> options.manifest.content['./node_modules/react-dom/lib/reactProdInvariant.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
>
> options.manifest.content['./node_modules/object-assign/index.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
>
> options.manifest.content['./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponentTree.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
>
> options.manifest.content['./node_modules/fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
>
> options.manifest.content['./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
>
> options.manifest.content['./node_modules/react/react.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property

And it just goes on and on for about 500 errors. There were no compile errors when the project was built. Here is my package.json:

```
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "^4.7.2",
    "@types/react": "~16.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "~16.0.9",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "~4.1.0",
    "@types/react-router": "~4.4.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "~4.3.1",
    "@types/seamless-immutable": "^7.1.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "~4.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "~4.3.12",
    "react-router-dom": "~4.3.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "4.25.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.4.0",
    "@types/deep-freeze": "^0.1.1",
    "@types/deep-freeze-es6": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.20.4",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "~1.1.7",
    "@types/react-virtualized": "~9.18.7",
    "a-react-timepicker": "~2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "deep-freeze-es6": "https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-freeze-es6/-/deep-freeze-es6-1.0.1.tgz",
    "history": "https://registry.npmjs.org/history/-/history-4.6.3.tgz",
    "react-datepicker": "~1.8.0",
    "react-timekeeper": "~1.0.9",
    "react-virtualized": "~9.21.0",
    "seamless-immutable": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "~16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.6.0",
    "moment": "2.20.0"
  }
```

Is anyone familiar with why this is happening? I've searched multiple posts and it seems like people always just have a couple errors. Not 500.

Comment: appears to be an issue with webpack and the `meta` option property.   You might want to downgrade the version of webpack you are using and/or file an issue with the webpack devs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved it or not , but I had the same problem when I updated to `Webpack 4` . The solution was to to run the `DllPlugin` from `webpack.config.vendor.js` so that `vendor-manifest.json` would get the latest attributes.

To do this, in `packages.json` put this line in the scripts section

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js",
  }
```

and from console run `npm run build`